# Integral Coefficients

Tags: math, integral, coefficients

I am reviewing a proof at the moment and there is terminology that I do not understand. What does it mean for a polynomial to have "integral coefficients"?

Comment: Off topic, but it simply means that the coefficients are integers -- aka whole numbers.

Comment: There's a [maths](https://math.stackexchange.com/) site on the network.

Comment: It would have been faster to use [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=Integral%20Coefficients).

Comment: This belongs on [mathematics.se], as it is a math question. This site is for programming (code) related questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Integral coefficients" means that the coefficients of your final answer will be integers, unless there is a markedly different context in which the question is being asked.

You can have a look at the definition [here](https://neeness.com/what-is-an-integral-coefficient/).